# jquery.validate.js - validate file name

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

According to the documentation for the jquery.validate plugin here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension

I can check the file extension of a file in order to validate the file extension, like so:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      accept: "xls|csv"
    }
  }
});
```

However this appears to have no effect on the field, I can still add any file to the field I like. The 'required' validation does work on the field and I have other fields on the page where the validation code works - however the 'accept' rule is just not being applied.

JSFiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/SCgRr

Comment: JSfiddle example added http://jsfiddle.net/SCgRr/

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the documentation is out of date, you need to include the `additional-methods.js` lib as well as `jquery.validate`.

Added the missing lib and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - specifically with `"xls|csv"` - even after including the `additional-methods.js`

Note this new paragraph http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension

> Note: This method used to look at just the filename, specifically the
>   file extension. That behaviour is now available as the "extension"
>   method inside additional-methods.js, same as this "accept" method
>   itself.

`accept` now specifies mimetype and `extension` is specific to the file name extension. Extensions like 'pdf' work - because the extension and mimetype are the same.   But xls and csv are text and need to be evaluated against the file name extension.

So changing `accept` to `extension` per the new doc worked for me.

Full code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      extension: "xls|csv"
    }
  }
});
```